# Write the query to get the below trail output from table 1 and table 2

Tags: sql

Table 1 : Family

```
Id  Name    Gender  
1   Ram        M    
2   shashank    m   
3   maya       f    
4   manu       f    
5   anu         f   
6   raj         m
```

Table 2 : Child_parent

```
Child_id    Parent_id       
1            2      
1            3      
4            5      
4            6
```

Write the query to get the below trail output

Output :

```
Child_id    Childname   father name   mother name
1           Ram         shashank       Maya
4           manu        raj            anu
```

Comment: Tables are not well designed!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky:

```
select cp.child_id, f.name,
       max(case when gender = 'm' then fp.name end) as father_name,
       max(case when gender = 'f' then fp.name end) as mother_name
from child_parent cp join
     family f
     on cp.child_id = f.id join
     family fp
     on cp.parent_id = fp.id
group by cp.child_id, f.name;
```